# Where on a List/Table in a Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select, multi-select

How can I do a where in a query on a list or table ?

To explain, I have a multiselect listbox where the user can select one or many values which are passed to my action. After that, I get all this values in a list and I want to do a Where on it like that :

```
List<string> CondCR = new List<string>();
foreach (var testCR in SubCR)
{
CondCR.Add(testCR);
}

ViewBag.CondCR = CondCR;

var query = (from i in items
where i.Field<String>("TIMING").Contains(GetTIMING) && i.Field<String>("CD_CR").Equals(CondCR)
select new Suivi{CD_CR = i.Field<String>("CD_CR"), CD_APPLI = i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI"), CD_TRT = i.Field<String>("CD_TRT"), LB_TRT = i.Field<String>("LB_TRT"), 
                PERIODE = i.Field<Int64>("PERIODE"), CD_JOB = i.Field<String>("CD_JOB"), LB_JOB = i.Field<String>("LB_JOB"), CD_TYP_TRT = i.Field<String>("CD_TYP_TRT"),
                CD_TRT_SSIS = i.Field<String>("CD_TRT_SSIS"), DT_DEB = i.Field<DateTime>("DT_DEB"), DT_FIN = i.Field<DateTime>("DT_FIN"), DUREE = i.Field<String>("DUREE"),
                TIMING = i.Field<String>("TIMING")
}).ToList();

return View(query);
```

SubCR contains the value that the user select in the list box, SubCR is of type string[].

I've tried to do a where on my list CondCR but it returns nothing and I don't know if it comes from my query or from an other thing.

Have you some suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've find the answer, I just had to do this in my query :

```
where CondCR.Contains(i.Field<String>("CD_CR").Trim()) && CondAppli.Contains(i.Field<String>("CD_APPLI").Trim())
```